# Finding the infinitesimal order of a function as $n \to \infty$

Tags: calculus, functions, infinitesimals

I have to find the infinitesimal order of a function $f(n)$ as $n \to \infty$,
this is what I did:

$$
\begin{split}
f(n) &= \sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n} + \frac{1}n \\
     &= \frac{n\sqrt{n+1} - n\sqrt{n} + 1}{n} \\
     &= \frac{\sqrt{n^3(1+\frac{1}{n^2})}-\sqrt{n^3}+1}{n} \\
     &= \frac{\sqrt{n^3}-\sqrt{n^3}+1}{n} \\
     &= \frac{1}{n} 
\end{split}
$$
**So the infinitesimal order is:** **1**

Is it correct? 
Or should I have used some notable limit, taylor or asymptomatic approximation.

Comment: Do you have a typo or two? Or are you using "$=$" to mean something other than "equals"?

Comment: I had one, I already correct it, it was 1/n instead of 1/2, the = means "equals"

Comment: @ElBryan : $\left( 1 + \frac{1}{n^2} \right) \neq 1$, so you are not using "$=$" to mean just "equals".

Comment: I see, then I'm wrong, I think I should have used "~"

Comment: Is the infinitesimal order = 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally it's easier to note that
$$
\sqrt{n+1}=\sqrt{n}\sqrt{1+1/n}\sim \sqrt{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)=\sqrt{n}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}},
$$
using the Taylor series for $\sqrt{1+x}$.  Then
$$
\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}+\frac{1}{n}\sim\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{n},
$$
with omitted terms $O(n^{-3/2})$.  The error in your original calculation is that $n\sqrt{n+1}=\sqrt{n^3+n^2}=\sqrt{n^3(1+1/n)}$, not $\sqrt{n^3(1+1/n^2)}$.

Comment: Your answer is -3/2, the other user answer is -1/2, which one is the correct?

Comment: No, both answers agree: $f(n)$ is asymptotic to a term of order $n^{-1/2}$ plus additional smaller terms.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider the following instead:
$$
\begin{split}
\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}
 &= \left(\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}\right) \times
    \frac{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}}\\
 &= \frac{n+1-n}{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}} \\
 &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}} \\
 &= \Theta\left(n^{-1/2}\right)
\end{split}
$$
therefore,
$$
\begin{split}
f(n)
 &= \sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n} + \frac1n \\
 &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}} + \frac1n \\
 &= \Theta\left(n^{-1/2} + n^{-1}\right) \\
 &= \Theta\left(n^{-1/2}\right)
\end{split}
$$

Comment: So my answer is wrong?, it was that easy....

Comment: @ElBryan your approach was incorrect, the error you ignored in your approximation was too big